# Creating a table with column sums which can be piped into kable

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, kable

I have a df which I would like to include in a repport with rmarkdown in html format:

```
df <- structure(list(n = 1:4, nn = c(14695L, 4304L, 264L, 36L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("n","nn"))



# A tibble: 4 x 2
      n    nn
  <int> <int>
1     1 14695
2     2  4304
3     3   264
4     4    36
```

I would like to add an extra row at the buttom with the following information:

```
df %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(nn))

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  total
  <int>
1 19299
```

And then pipe the result in `kable`. I would like the sum to be in bold. How do I achive this?
Thanks.

Comment: is your report html/pdf/word/etc.?

Comment: @ snoram: html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
df %>% 
  bind_rows(., tibble(nn = sum(.[["nn"]]))) %>%
  kable() %>%
  row_spec(5, bold = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: More `kableExtra` functionalities: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: @ snoram: Thanks. Can you explain the dot in the tidyverse packages. I understand that it just means the data set, but here you pipe df to the first argument so why have the dot? Okay I think you use the dot so you can use it in the ``sum``.

Comment: @ Also is ``options(knitr.kable.NA = '')`` a global option and if yes how can I reset it to default?

Comment: @ snoram: Is there a way to only set the option for the current table?

Comment: @David 1. the dot is not tidyverse but `magrittr` and adopted by the tidyverse, it just refers to what's left of the pipe be it dataset or something else. 2. You probably can (not sure how) but  you can change it back to default with `options(knitr.kable.NA = NULL)`.